# User input in already given range for Python pattern

Tags: python

I need help. I want to print pattern in already specified range let's say from 4 to 17 and to print the pattern for any user input in that range. Let's say the user wants to enter number 5. The pattern should look like this:

[image: pattern]

But I don't know how to limit range. I have used this code

```
n = int(input('Enter number in range 4 to 17'))
for i in range(4, n+1, 1):
    for j in range(4, i + 1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
for i in range(n, 4, -1):
    for j in range(4, i):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method

```
n = int(input('Enter number in range 4 to 17: '))

if n>4 and n<17:
    for i in range(n+1):
        print("*"*i)
        
    for j in range(n-1,0,-1):
        print("*"*j)
```

output

```
Enter number in range 4 to 17: 5

*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, you could start your code with a loop to ask user input until it is correct:

```
n = 0
while 4 > n > 17:
    n = int(input('Enter number in range 4 to 17'')

# rest of code
```

Comment: I think it should be like this? while 4 < n < 17:

Comment: @PythonLearner No, here we want to stay in the loop when the values are **not** in the range, and leave it once it is correct.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding it, just run the code and see ;)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code I would use a "while True" loop until the user enters a value within the desired range.

To ensure this, include inside the loop some conditionals as in the example below.

Also include a notice for the user.

```
while True:
  n = int(input('Enter number in range 4 to 17'))
  if n >= 4 and n <=17:
    for i in range(n+1):
      for j in range(i):
          print('*', end='')
      print()
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
      for j in range(i):
        print('*', end='')
      print()
  break
  else:
    print('Value out range')
```

Comment: Your `break` has a wrong indentation level, it should be in the if ;)

Comment: Thank you @Leonardo I prefer not to use while loop, since I just want user to enter the number in given range once and get the result.